# linux scripting with a variable referring to id's in a text file OR mass citrix vm snapshot delete

Tags: linux, shell, citrix

I have a command (citrix xenserver cli delete snapshot command--if it matters) that I have to repeat a bunch of times:

```
xe snapshot-uninstall snapshot-uuid=[snapshot-uuid]
```

I want to script this using a variable for [snapshot-uuid] so that I can repeat for all lines in a text file that looks like this (each line is a unique uuid wth no whitespace):

```
dd56e7d2-00b0-4ddd-b3bf-368e3de059f9
ba201e7e-c180-4e00-8134-2ea128c9a14e
32128f38-b1b5-40e7-848c-dbdf5ae255ed
b53145ec-3748-475d-8add-008665533f72
173cb6c4-04da-43bc-abce-f2c97f76d3d2
3829f365-e619-47a0-93cd-d5aca37c28dd
6eb7aff9-70f9-4a77-96b0-044dfb0ce96e
ca7478c6-eae1-4090-aed5-c348b172d12a
439e247d-cf6a-4f09-a4d7-8dc719c317ca
b595d2e8-e2c4-4d0e-9b07-cccf1108904b
1da57650-dc16-48e2-bf5f-e2b8b96dba03
f2718a31-baa8-4c74-b170-5933e71da8c4
b2263c61-175e-43fa-b941-52ec2379a835
d0d6ede9-0589-4908-884f-900fef1d1c92
65e54f20-8c33-4f67-a394-36676add54ac
6d0f388c-5a78-4962-b1b2-55117b18a4c9
```

An additional complication is that with each command an "are you sure... type 'yes' to continue" is given.

UPDATE: I originally posted this question because my question on Citrix's Xenserver CLI forum had been ignored. I did later get a response on the Citrix forum [here](http://forums.citrix.com/thread.jspa?threadID=277090&tstart=0), which included a command that is far more efficient than what I was trying to do. Please, if ever anyone has a need to delete all snapshots, use the following:

```
for i in `xe snapshot-list --minimal | sed -e 's/,/\ /g'` ; do xe snapshot-uninstall force=true uuid=$i ; done
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a shell script to loop over each line:

```
#!/bin/bash

while read UUID; do
    yes | xe snapshot-uninstall snapshot-uuid="$UUID"
done < uuids.txt
```

Or if you're a good typist you can enter all three lines of the while loop directly at your shell.

You can auto-answer any prompts by piping the output of `yes`. `yes` will repeatedly print the string of your choice (default "y"):

> #### Name
>
> yes - output a string repeatedly until killed
>
> #### Synopsis
>
> ```
> yes [STRING]...
> ```
>
> #### Description
>
> Repeatedly output a line with all specified STRING(s), or ‘y’.

Comment: This would have worked, except for the "type 'yes' to continue" I mention in my edit above. Should I post a new question for that issue? +1 for your help thus far. Thanks.

Comment: If I had some bounty and knew how to give it to you I would. You rock!

Answer (score 1):

```
xargs -I % -a uuidfile xe snapshot-uninstall snapshot-uuid=%
```

To respond to "are you sure" prompts:

```
xargs -I % -a sh -c 'yes | uuidfile xe snapshot-uninstall snapshot-uuid=%'
```

Comment: @John: You're right. I had it in there first and then didn't take it out. I will now.